# How to set up https on kubernetes bare metal using traefik ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, traefik-ingress

I'm running a kubernetes cluster which consists of three nodes and brilliantly works, but it's time to make my web application secure, so I deployed an ingress controller(traefik). But I was unable to find instructions for setting up https on it. I know most of things I will have to do, like setting up a "secret"(container with certs) etc. but I was wondering how to configure my ingress controller and all files related to it so I would be able to use secure connection

I have already configured ingress controller and created some frontends and backends. Also I configured nginx server(It's actually a web application I'm running) to work on 443 port

---

## My web application deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3 # tells deployment to run 3 pods matching the template
  template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: ilchub/my-nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 443
      tolerations:
      - key: "primary"
        operator: Equal
        value: "true"
        effect: "NoSchedule"
```

---

## Traefik ingress controller deployment code

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: traefik
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: secure
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 8080
        args:
        - --api
        - --kubernetes
        - --logLevel=INFO
```

---

## Ingress for traefik dashboard

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cluster.aws.ctrlok.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: traefik-web-ui
          servicePort: web
```

---

## External expose related config

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30036
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      nodePort: 30035
      name: secure
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      nodePort: 30034
      name: admin
  type: NodePort
```

What I want to do is securing my application which is already running. Final result has to be a webpage running over https

Comment: I'm curious why you chose to run only 1 replica for Traefik but 3 in your Nginx configuration.  I'm trying to track down a intermittent timeout issue we are seeing when running more than 1 replica for the Traefik ingress controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have 3 ways to configure Traefik to use https to communicate with backend pods:

1. If the service port defined in the ingress spec is 443 (note that you can still use targetPort to use a different port on your pod).
2. If the service port defined in the ingress spec has a name that starts with https (such as https-api, https-web or just https).
3. If the ingress spec includes the annotation ingress.kubernetes.io/protocol: https.

If either of those configuration options exist, then the backend communication protocol is assumed to be TLS, and will connect via TLS automatically.

Also additional authentication [annotations](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/#authentication) should be added to the Ingress object, like:

`ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: secret`

And of course, [add a TLS Certificate to the Ingress](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/#add-a-tls-certificate-to-the-ingress)